# Best Practice in MySQL for Storing a Field With N Possible Values

Tags: mysql, database-design

In my application, which relies on tables of data, each entry needs to have its state recorded, and there are four possible states. I want to know what the best way is to represent one of these four states in a table column and how the method would generalize to N states using MySQL.

**EDIT**

Clarified that I want to only want to represent a single state at a time, not multiple

Comment: I would imagine that the strategy for storing 4 states and the strategy for storing n states might differ.

Comment: Do you intend to store just one state, out of four possible states?  Or do you mean to store a set of four states, possibly a history of states?

Comment: Do you mean use a code to represent the state and have a separate lookup table? That is what is commonly used.

Comment: If your state is an object, you can just store it as a json string. as long as you don't plan on querying that data. I know mssql has a json data type which kind of makes it nosql like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
`state` ENUM('ready', 'active', 'removed', 'foobared')
```

Is a straightforward way to have 'small' number of mutually exclusive values for a column.  Although you can have hundreds of options, 2 is common, and 4 is 'ok'.  It is somewhat clumsy to add yet another option, but it is possible.  `ENUM` takes 1 byte so it is very efficient; you reference the values by the strings indicated, making the code human-friendly.

If the "states" are not mutually exclusive, see the `SET` datatype.

(There are proponents and opponents of using `ENUM` -- I expect to get flamed for suggesting `ENUM`.)

You can still have another table to add verbose descriptions for the states:

```
CREATE TABLE StateMeanings (
    `state` ENUM(... (as above)),
    `description` VARCHAR(188) );

INSERT INTO StateMeanings (`state`, `description`)
    VALUES
    ('ready', "The horse is saddled, and the groom is standing by."),
    ...
```